# The quest "A New Source of Stalhrim" won't start because Baldor never gets kidnapped

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

As I just said in the title, the quest "A New Source of Stalhrim" won't start because Baldor never gets kidnapped. He's still there as if nothing has happened, there is never dialogue from Deor Woodcutter talking about him being kidnapped because he never was.

Because I can not complete this quest, the word wall at the end of "Lost Legacy" is unreachable.

I have already completed "The Fate of the Skaal" a while ago, so that's not the issue. If your answer involves console commands, I might've already done that command but don't hesitate to say so.